# ZfcUser - state always null on registration

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am trying to implement ZfcUser in my first Zend Framework 2 project. I have run the SQL to create the User Table and copied the zfcuser.global.php into the autoload folder. I want to use the "state" column in the db.I was thinking that if I change the below 3 entries in the zfcuser.global.php, the state would be automatically 1 in the database, when a User registered, but all I get is null. I have tried to search through the interenet, but noone else seem to have this problem. What am I doing wrong here? Any advice or do I assume something which does not happen?

```
/**
 * Enable user state usage
 * 
 * Should user's state be used in the registration/login process?
 */
'enable_user_state' => true,

/**
 * Default user state upon registration
 * 
 * What state user should have upon registration?
 * Allowed value type: integer
 */
'default_user_state' => 1,

/**
 * States which are allowing user to login
 * 
 * When user tries to login, is his/her state one of the following?
 * Include null if you want user's with no state to login as well.
 * Allowed value types: null and integer
 */
'allowed_login_states' => array( 1 ),
```

Comment: Are you overwriting the user Service?
What version are you using?

Comment: This is what I used for composer, I suppose I pulled the latest Versions with this? "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*", "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master", Otherwise I have done no additional change. How would I know if I overwrite the User Service? Sorry, I am still a beginner...

Comment: I have my own User Entity (does that mean I overwrite the user Service?), but have copied the setState() and getState() from the zfcUser Entity, but it is still null in the Database.